# Function not working even though variable looks fine

Tags: powershell

Function should end up doing like this and running the command:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter  'system.web/customErrors'  -name  'mode'
```

However variable gets messed up like this with current working directory added and backslashes:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\username\'MACHINE\WEBROOT\APPHOST\Default Web Site''
because it does not exist
```

ECHO looks fine and also redirect to file is fine as well:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter  'system.web/customErrors'  -name  'mode'
```

Sample run:

```
PS C:\temp> Get-Check-Func2 "webcA" "mode" "system.web/customErrors"
'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'
system.web/customErrors
mode

Get-WebConfigurationProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\username\'MACHINE\WEBROOT\APPHOST\Default Web Site''
because it does not exist.
At line:10 char:16
+ ...             Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath ` $mypspath ` -filte ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\usern...fault Web Site':String) [Get-WebConfigurationProperty
   ], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.GetConfigurationPropertyCommand

Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath  'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site' -filter  'system.web/customErrors'  -name  'mode'
```

Please be kind as I am a newbie to PowerShell.

Coming from korn/bash background.

```
function Get-Check-Func2 {
$a = Get-Website
$myws = $a.Name
$mypspath = 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/' + "$myws"
$mypspath = '''' + $mypspath + ''''
$myfilter = '''' +  $args[2] + ''''
$myname = '''' +  $args[1] + ''''
 echo "$mypspath"
 echo $args[2]
           Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath ` $mypspath ` -filter ` $myfilter ` -name ` $myname
     echo "Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath ` $mypspath ` -filter ` $myfilter ` -name ` $myname"
     }
```

Expect  Get-WebConfigurationProperty to run but seems like variable gets messed up.

Comment: Don't put your variables inside single-quotes with stuff like this: `$mypspath = '''' + $mypspath + ''''`. Simply use the variables and `$args` as they are and leave out all the backticks aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Your backticks might be causing the issue. Instead of this:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath ` $mypspath ` -filter ` $myfilter ` -name ` $myname
```

Just do this:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $mypspath -filter $myfilter -name $myname
```

Or if you're trying to multiline it, only put the backtick after each parameter / input pair, e.g:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $mypspath `
                             -filter $myfilter `
                             -name $myname
```

Another popular option for providing lots of parameters to a cmdlet in a way that doesn't end up with a very long single line is to use a concept called [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting). For example:

```
$GetWebConfigPropertyParams = @{
    PSPath = $mypspath
    Filter = $myfilter
    Name = $myname
}
Get-WebConfigProperty @GetWebConfigPropertyParams
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mark.
Tried all above and still same issue.


function Get-Check-Func2 {
$a = Get-Website
$myws = $a.Name
$mypspath = 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/' + "$myws"
$mypspath = '''' + $mypspath + ''''
$myfilter = '''' +  $args[2] + ''''
$myname = '''' +  $args[1] + ''''
 echo "$mypspath"
 echo "$myname"
 $GetWebConfigPropertyParams = @{
    PSPath = $mypspath
    Filter = $myfilter
    Name = $myname
} ....

Comment: PS C:\Users\username> Get-Check-Func2 "webcA" "mode" "system.web/customErrors" 
'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'
'mode'
-PSPath:
'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'
-Filter:
'system.web/customErrors'
-Name:
'mode'
Get-WebConfigurationProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\username\'MACHINE\WEBROOT\APPHOST\Default Web Site'' because it does 
not exist.
At line:16 char:1

Comment: At line:16 char:1
+ Get-WebConfigurationProperty @GetWebConfigPropertyParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\usern...fault Web Site':String) [Get-WebConfigurationProperty], ItemNotFoun 
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.GetConfigurationPropertyCommand
 
Get-WebConfigurationProperty
-PSPath:
'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'
-Filter:
'system.web/customErrors'
-Name:
'mode'

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did have the right idea Mark ... my apologies.
Also got some input from another powershell guru :-)
This works fine now!

```
function Check-Webca-Select {
param(
$WebsitePSPath  = 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/',
$Filter , 
$ComponentName,
$Myexpect
)
 $a = get-website
 $w = $a.name
  foreach ($WebsiteName in $w) {
   $WebsiteFullPath = "{0}{1}" -f $WebsitePSPath,$WebsiteName
   Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "$WebsiteFullPath" -Filter $Filter -Name $ComponentName | Select-String "$Myexpect"
 }
}
```

### exec sample

Check-Webca-Select -Filter "system.web/customErrors" -ComponentName "mode" -Myexpect "Remoteonly"